# Dynamically Creating pages based on user's input

Tags: php, jquery, html, wysiwyg

I have an article website. So far, all my articles have been created by me working with the code. Copying and pasting the code and editing the P tags, H1 tags, etc. This turns out to be a hassle and increases the chance of you making an error. Especially when the article has multiple pages.

Future-wise, I want users to create articles. So this is what I want: User clicks on button that says 'create an article' and then the user gets redirected to the article builder page where they can make an article for themselves. The user will create a name for their article, this name will create a folder on my server...for example: www.example.com/articles/name-of-article. Then the user can write the article. The user will abide by classes I have created for tags, but those tags will not be seen by the user. The user only sees that their content is getting adjusted well based on my CSS template. Also, if the user wants to add another page to the article, they can put in already built buttons...they just have to change the links to those buttons. The user should also have the ability to bold, underline, and italicize text.

Note: Users are working with a pre-built template, not a blank page. The template article includes a recommended panel, showing other articles. The user does not have permission to edit this panel.

I've heard about WYSIWYG HTML editors, but I just want to know if this is the right thing for what I want. Is there something else that can accomplish my task better? If WYSIWYG is the best answer, can it do everything I've asked for?

P.S: My article pages are PHP pages, with HTML and Javascript included.

Comment: Sorry... Whattt? Did you try Wordpress? It could make you forget about trying to reinvent it. I may be in the woods... But...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write html codes of articels in php. I would suggest you to use a content management system (CMS) like [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/).

Comment: I'm not writing the article contents in PHP, the PHP is for me including the header and footer so I can dynamically add changes to it. I don't use WordPress, and wish to stay at my current hosting. Do you know anything about WYSIWYG HTML editors?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a CMS. Wordpress is the best approach for your needs, but if you can't use it, you can search for other CMS systems/frameworks.

If you want to make/use your own, just remember to do a Template framework.

And appart of your main question about WYSIWYG, yes, you can do all you asked if it can be done with PHP.

Comment: So if I don't want to use Wordpress, I could use a WYSIWYG software? Is WYSIWYG a CMS as well and can I use a template for WYSIWYG?

Comment: No, WYSIWYG is a way of "doing something"... WYSIWYG stands for "What You See Is What You Get"... So, any WYSIWYG HTML input will output exactly What You See. You should save that HTML output and show that in any webpage you want. [Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-best-html-wysiwyg-plugins/) for example.

Comment: No to which question? My main question would be can I accomplish the tasks I want using a WYSIWYG Editor from the link you provided?

Comment: All the tasks including creating/moving forlders and all of that, that is not `plain text` (just text, doesnt matter if formatted or not), no. You can only formmat text.